# Subtree merge into multiple directories

Tags: git

I have two repositories and one of them (*shared*) contains some shared libraries used by the code in the other one (*main*).

```
main
+--- foo
|    +--- shared
|    +...
+----bar
|    +--- shared
.    +...
```

I have added *shared* as a remote to my local *main* working copy and I'm trying to merge the master branches using the subtree strategy:

```
git merge --squash -s subtree shared/master
```

This command automagically finds an appropriate directory and does the merge.
However, when there is more than one place that the shared branch should be merged into, it only merges it into one place (looks like it's taking the first one in alphabetical order).

Is there a way to force it to continue and do the merge into all matching places?

Comment: I suggest you keep the `shared/` directory in one location and make symbolic links from all the places in the directory tree where it is needed.